# Nav component not rendering properly in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I am trying to run the code its not rendering properly,each nav component is sticking to each other rather than a proper looking nav bar.

```
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">Home</li> 
                        <li> About </li>
                        <li> Products </li>
                        <li> Login </li>
                        <li> Trending </li>
                        <li> Contact </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `<form>` tag surrounding your `nav` and why does your `nav` not have a `<nav>` tag?

Comment: witch bootstrap for used ?

Comment: and i agree with you @NeilPatrao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a anchor tag inside `li`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
                    <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Products</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a>  </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trending</a>  </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>  </li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>  
    </form>

</div>
```